# What's the difference between tf.train.ExponentialMovingAverage and tf.train.MomentumOptimizer?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I have seen the doc, tf.train.ExponentialMovingAverage implement this formula:

```
shadow_variable = decay * shadow_variable + (1 - decay) * variable
```

I didn't find the formula of tf.train.MomentumOptimizer. But I think it may be:

```
v = γ*v - learning_rate*dx
θ = θ - v
```

I think this two function have similar effect, so can they exchange each other?Or they have different application scenarios? Or I'm totally wrong?

And does the shadow_variable is equivalent to θ?

Thanks for any guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're totally wrong.

`tf.train.ExponentialMovingAverage` implements **just** the exponential moving average: the `shadow_variable` is the moving average at the current time step and it's updated using the formula you posted.
Every time you execute the node that holds the moving average, what happens is **just** the execution of that formula.

The `tf.train.MomentumOptimizer`, instead, is a way more complex object.
In short, it implements a parameter update algorithm called Gradient Descent with Momentum that computes the gradient of the model parameters and executes the update step of every single network parameter using the computed gradient + the momentum term that's accumulated over the training steps.

The momentum term is, of course, the moving average of the gradients. But the two functions execute different operations and have different aims.

Comment: Thanks for your guidance. ^_^ I understand it now. And I have another question. When we use tf.train.ExponentialMovingAverage.apply(var) to maintains moving averages of variables, then if we update a variable such as use tf.assign, to get decayed variable, we will use tf.train.ExponentialMovingAverage.average(var), but if we get the variable directly by tf.Session.run(var), we will get the variable without decay. So when we train a neural network with ExponentialMovingAverage, does the model use the decayed variable by tf.train.ExponentialMovingAverage.average() default?

Comment: You should open another question for this :D

Comment: Ok, thanks for your reminding, I have open another question now ^_^